# Accessing the User Information List using C# (server object model)

Tags: sharepoint-addin

While retrieving the User Information List, by using the following code,

```
SPListItemCollection InformationList = userInformationList.Items;

                    Parallel.ForEach(InformationList.Cast<SPListItem>(), listItem =>
                    {
                        var employeeDetails = new Employee();
                        var accountname = Convert.ToString(listItem["Name"]).ToLower();
                        if (accountname.StartsWith(@"i:0#.w|jordan\"))
                        {
                            if(listItem["ID"] != null)
                            { 
                            employeeDetails.Number = Convert.ToString(listItem["ID"]);
                            employeeDetails.Name = Convert.ToString(listItem["Title"]);
                            employeeDetails.EmailID = Convert.ToString(listItem["EMail"]);
                            EmployeeList.Add(employeeDetails);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

getting the `IDs` as `NULL` at certain times, though proper values at certain times. I'm using `ForEach` coz., my site is having large count of users.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting proper values at certain times, that could mean, it is data issue, not a coding problem!

Try to access the user profile using REST (for 2013 or above) and see if the values coming back.

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't able to reproduce the NULL check case., . If am getting that back again, will let you.